# Update to network profiles

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, network-profile

The new profile pages on the SE websites are at least in my opinion far better than the old ones.

It would be great to see the style come to the network profile on StackExchange.com, so that you can see an overview of everything about your user on all sites.

Comment: What, in your opinion, makes them *better*? The fact that they include information about your participation on other sites in the network? Yes, and that's fantastic, but we don't want to show that information on your *per-site* profile. It should only show information for *that* site.

Comment: @TheEstablishment, the new profiles only show information about the site that you are on, except for the very small section about accounts. The point of StackExchange.com user profiles is to collate your participation on all SE sites. imo, what makes the new ones better is that they show you Reputation, Questions, Answers, Tags, Badges, Votes, and Accounts all on one page, whereas the old profiles (on Stackexchange.com) only shows you about Questions and Answers on the first page. Also I'm all for continuity and being uniform